# Json Editor Plugin installation?

Tags: eclipse, json, eclipse-plugin

I feel really stupid by asking this question, but how can I install Json Editor Plugin in my Eclipse Helios? I looked at the Forum in sourceforge, but I can't install it neither through .zip or by adding a web site. And will I need to change the execution environment to Java 1.6?

Comment: can't help there, but thought i'd atleast let you know you aren't alone in the world and there are many others who have had a painful time installing plugins in eclipse. good ide but bad update / plugin mechanism

Comment: Don't feel stupid, this helped me today. Have an upvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what I did to get the Json Editor Plugin to show up in the Install Dialog.

By doing a little Google-ing, I found [this page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/forums/forum/957258/topic/3311846) which describes the steps to install JsonEditorPlugin on 3.4.

After you have followed the first 6 steps, make sure that *Group items by category* is **un-ticked**.  After that, you can then choose Json Editor Plugin to be installed from the local Zip archive that you have downloaded from the net.

Edit: as a side note, you must not have the unzipped contents of the zip archive in the dropins/ folder, otherwise it will appear as if the plugin is already installed.

Simply dropping the zip contents into the dropins folder however did work also.

Note: You must right click your .json file and choose 'Open with' -> 'Json Editor'

Answer (score 1):

You can install plugins by just unzipping them into the **dropins** folder.
It does not matter if the zip file contains the parent folders "plugins" and/or "eclipse".

I would recommend Java 1.6 as it brings a better performance and the plugin might require Java 1.6. On your desktop shortcut you use following execution arguments:

```
eclipse -vm <path to jre 1.6 installation folder>\bin\javaw
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Download jsonedit-repository-0.9.7.zip (or whatever) and put it in a folder you like.
2. In Eclipse Help --> Install New Software
3. Add --> Archive button and select the zip file.
4. Name it and press OK
5. Press button Next and Follow master of installation.

Then after opening json file possibly needed right click mouse on the file --> open with --> JSON editor